# Using Metadata for data types when writing to a database

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to copy some large data tables on a regular basis from one database to another. Looking for a fast transfer between the 2 databases without data types changing during the process e.g. boolean converting to text.

I started with pandas `read_sql_table()` and `to_sql()` which does a good job retaining the original data types into the new database. However, these to do run rather slow for 1M+ rows of data.

Next, I've tried using temporary CSV files with `COPY` statements. This drastically improves the copying and writing time of a table to the new database. However, I'm losing the original data types during this process; date becoming datetime, boolean becoming text. Ideally I don't want to have additional code to re-convert data types in the database.

Currently, I've been exploring the idea of using `sqlalchemy` to copy a table and using the table's metadata to write a table into a new database with it's original data types.

```py
import sqlalchemy as db
engine = db.create_engine("postgresql+psycopg2://username:password@/database?host=datawarehouse")
connection = engine.connect()

# Gets metadata of the customers table
metadata = db.MetaData()
metadata.reflect(bind=engine)
metadata.tables['customers']

# Gets data from the customers table
customers = db.Table('customers', metadata, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)
query = db.select([customers])
ResultProxy = connection.execute(query)
ResultSet = ResultProxy.fetchall()
```

The data comes into python as list (list of lists) which copies fast (similar speed as temporary CSV process).

Is there a way to push the data into a new table with data types specified from the metadata?

I'm hoping there is a way to transfer large tables fast without losing the original datatypes, particularly booleans. Plus, be generalizable for many tables.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use COPY ... WITH BINARY. It will preserves original data types.

Comment: Thanks @IvanMogila for the suggestion. 'WITH BINARY' seems what I'm looking for. However, how can I get a tangible dataframe from `COPY {schema}.{table} TO STDOUT WITH BINARY`? With temporary CSV one can use `pd.read_csv()`, what is the equivalent for binary? Thanks